# Отображение кнопок для выбора языка на сайте

Tags: html, веб-программирование

Есть сайт на нескольких языках. Как лучше отобразить кнопки (или просто ссылки) для выбора языка?

1. Показывать все языки, выделять выбранный.
2. Показывать те, на которые можно переключиться, то есть все, кроме выбранного.
3. Показывать выбранный язык, по нажатию - меню с возможностью выбора.

Может есть какой-нибудь общепринятый вариант?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это зависит от количества и представления языков.

- Если языков мало (до двух), можно показать их одним флагом или кодом iso, причем показывать тот, на который будет переключение. Это логично, потому что это будет единственная кнопка, на которую будут кликать, не зная языка.
- Если языков несколько (до десяти), можно показать их рядом, при этом выделяя размером или цветом текущий язык.
- Если языков много, то остается либо сделать выпадающий список, либо выделить под таблицу языков отдельную страницу (пример - microsoft.com).

Answer (score 0):

скорее общепринятый - это более используемый. более крупные сайты (microsoft) используют выбор из списка, т.к. там языков много, более мелкие делают ссылки вроде: RU EN FR DE ES CN, при этом выделяются используемый язык, и на него нажать нельзя. это скорее вопрос вкуса